# Windows XP "Windows Search" does not find all documents with FileName but Search Companion does

Tags: windows-xp, windows-search

I'm using Windows XP Pro with Windows Search 4.0.

If I search for filename *postage*  I get once result from my local S:\ drive (which is being Indexed)   (result is : postage.doc)

If I search using the Search Assistant, I get 5 or 10 results (which I know are valid files) on the S: drive. (results : PostageChart.xls, Postage Transaction Record.pdf)

(And BTW, I'm looking into Agent Ransack as an alternative, but I'd like to get Windows Search 4 working so that I can search this fileserver from another PC running Windows 7 (and it needs Windows Search running on this fileserver to search it across the network)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things you can check if you pull up the options for the search deskbar.  Open the Advanced Options.  Under File Types, make sure there is a checkbox next to all the file types you want included in the index.  Some of them may have been excluded by default or accident.  Under the Index Settings tab, try a Rebuild of the index.  This helped a problem I was having a few months back where my index had apparently become corrupted.

Also, make sure that you've checked "Index Content and filename" (not just filename) if you want to search the contents of the files.

Comment: The files it didn't find are selected as "to be indexed" however, it was set to only the file names not contents. (Doesn't solve the problem reported here but might solve a related one)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your examples it look like under advanced options your search is marked as case sensitive.

Comment: The Windows Search add-on for XP (which gives it Vista/Win7-like search) ignores case in all searches.  Only the Search Companion (the "legacy" search box) supports case-sensitive searches.

Comment: I confirmed that the Win XP Search is indeed NOT case sensitive.